# python get new value in a class or method

Tags: python, variables

i'am new to python and try to get the new value for my bool in a class .

i try create a global, set in the init.

How can i get the new value of the test bool in getnewvalue() ?

Here is my code :

```
test = False

class myclass():
   def changevalue()
       test = True
       getnewvalue()

   def getnewvalue():
       print(test)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Do you want to change the *module*-level (global) value of `test`, or do you want to attach `test` to the *class object* (as an instance attribute)? And what are you going to use it for? Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). You can [edit] to clarify. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: And what do you mean by "init"? "The code before the class"? Or is `myclass` supposed to have an `__init__` method?

Comment: Also, in this code, `myclass.changevalue()` is never run, so the value of `test` is never modified in any scope...?

Comment: Also, what are those methods supposed to be? If they're supposed to be static methods, they should be decorated with `@staticmethod`. But then why would they be in a class that has no other functionality? You might need to learn more about classes before trying to use them.

Comment: Also, `getnewvalue` is not defined inside `changevalue`. You might have meant `myclass.getnewvalue()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have data inside your class, it's a good idea to use the `__init__()`
and save it like that. More here in the Python tutorial: [Class Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).

And use the `__init__` to initialize the class with desired values.
Your code should look something like this:

```py
test = False

class myclass():

    def __init__(self, test):
        self.test = test  # self keyword is used to access/set attrs of the class
        # __init__() gets called when the object is created, if you want to call
        # any function on the creation of the object after setting the values
        # you can do it here
        self.changevalue()

    def changevalue(self):  # if you want to access the values of the class you
                            # need to pass self as a argument to the function 
        self.test = not test
        self.getnewvalue()

    def getnewvalue(self):
        print(self.test)  # use self to access objects test value

_class = myclass(False)
```

Or if you just want to have a class with functions, you can do something like this:

```
test = False

class myclass():

    @staticmethod
    def changevalue(val)
        return not val

    @staticmethod
    def getnewvalue(test):
        print(test)

_class = myclass()
test = _class.changevalue(test)
```

This way it won't print your value on call because it's just setting your value to return of that function. You'll have to do it yourself but that shouldn't be a problem.
More about staticmethods here: [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

Comment: You forgot `@staticmethod` on `def getnewvalue`. Apart from that, this is a good answer! I'm not sure if it's what OP's looking for since the question is unclear, but hopefully it at least shows OP exactly what they *don't* want :P We recommend avoiding answering unclear questions until OP clarifies. See [answer] under "Answer well-asked questions".

Comment: thank's for all, i'am very beginner and this help me a lot to understand .

Answer (score -1):

Add

```py
global test
```

to both functions. The resulting code would be...

```py
test = False

class myclass():
   def changevalue():
       global test
       test = True
       getnewvalue()

   def getnewvalue():
       global test
       print(test)
```

`global` allows the function to access variables outside of itself.
Hope this helps!

Comment: *"`global` allows the function to access variables outside of itself."* -- No, it allows a function to *modify* a name in the *global* scope (not just any outer scope -- that's what `nonlocal` is for). So declaring `global test` in `getnewvalue()` is not necessary. Functions can always *access* outer scopes.

Comment: Also, `getnewvalue` is not defined inside `changevalue()`, but that's OP's mistake, not yours.

Comment: @wjandrea, Thanks for the feedback! I was writing it as easy to understand. Also I just find it good practice to use `global` in any function when needed. Mainly so editors won't freak-out and also as just a good way to keep track of what's using what during debugging.